# Does this integral converge? $\int_0^\infty e^{\large{x/2-2\alpha(x^2-x^{1+\delta})}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I am stuck on showing whether this integral converges or not:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{\large{x/2-2\alpha(x^2-x^{1+\delta})}}\mathrm dx$$
where $\alpha>0$ and $0<\delta<1$.  This seems pretty simple, and I think that it should converge, however, I can't see how to prove it (perhaps it doesn't converge?)  Any hints?

Comment: $$\int_0^\infty e^{\huge{x/2-2\alpha(x^2-x^{1+\delta})}}\mathrm dx$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large $x$, the integrand is dominant by

$$ e^{-2\alpha x^2}. $$

Answer (score 1):

Given $\delta \in (0,1)$, we have for $x>x_0(\delta)$,
$$x^2 - x^{1+\delta} \geq \dfrac{x^2}{2\alpha}$$
This gives us for $x>x_0(\delta)$
$$e^{x/2-2\alpha(x^2-x^{1+\delta})} = e^{x/2-x^2}$$
Now you should be able to show that the integral converges.